# Simple SQL problem (MySQL)

Tags: sql, mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT page.id, revision.title, revision.number
FROM page
    INNER JOIN revision ON page.id = revision.pageId
```

Which will return something like:

```
"1"   "Page Version A"   "1"
"1"   "Page Version B"   "2"
"1"   "Page Version C"   "3"
```

Now I only want to return one row for each page, with the data from the latest (highest numbered) revision. If I do:

```
SELECT page.id, revision.title, revision.number
FROM page
    INNER JOIN revision ON page.id = revision.pageId
GROUP BY page.id
```

I get:

```
"1"   "Page Version A"   "1"
```

But I want:

```
"1"   "Page Version C"   "3"
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a WHERE clause similar to

WHERE revision.number = (select max(number) from revision r where r.pageId = page.id)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to select a single record you could use the MySQL 'LIMIT' keyword (similar to MSSQL 'TOP')

eg:

```
SELECT page.id, revision.title, revision.number
FROM page
    INNER JOIN revision ON page.id = revision.pageId

ORDER BY revision.number DESC
LIMIT 0, 1
```

This will order all of your results, then select the top result.

Comment: this solution is faster than Rahul's one!

Answer (score 0):

If this is a query you will run many times, I would consider to make a view which selects the most recent revision per pageid:

```
create view LatestRevision
as 
Select pageid, max(number) from revision
```

then the query would be

```
SELECT page.id, revision.title, revision.number
FROM page
    INNER JOIN revision ON page.id = revision.pageId
    INNER JOIN LatestRevision on revision.pageid = LatestRevision.pageid and revision.Number = LatestRevision.number
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT page.id, MAX(revision.number)
FROM page
INNER JOIN revision ON page.id = revision.pageId
GROUP BY page.id
```

Comment: This will only select the maximum of the revision number, not the entire latest revision.